# Determine if iOS permission prompt is showing

Tags: ios

This is what I need to figure out: how do I detect if a system permission prompt is currently visible? I know how to detect if a UIAlertView is visible, but those methods don't work when it comes to the permission prompts.

Comment: Why do you need to know if it is showing, instead of knowing when you show it yourself? you can control when to ask for permission.

Comment: and what permission do you need to get?

Comment: I need this because it's not guaranteed that the prompt will actually show up. It happens the first time, but it's unsure whether or not subsequent requests will actually show the prompt.

Comment: The answer is, you can't. If you really want to, I would store a flag in `NSUserDefaults` that you set after the first time you request permission.